Spring Boot 3.2.4 + Springdoc OpenAPI: "No operations defined in spec!" in Swagger UI
I'm working on a Spring Boot application (version 3.2.4) and using Springdoc OpenAPI (version 2.0.4) to generate API documentation. However, when I open Swagger UI, I see the message "No operations defined in spec!".
This is my whole project.
Here are the relevant details of my setup:
pom.xml (dependencies related to Springdoc OpenAPI):
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>

SetupController.java:
package blossom.reports_service.inbound;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import blossom.reports_service.model.ChallengeSummary;
import blossom.reports_service.model.ReportsService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/setup")
public class SetupController {

    private final ReportsService reportsService;

    @Autowired
    public SetupController(ReportsService reportsService) {
        this.reportsService = reportsService;
    }

    @PostMapping("/createChallengeSummary/{userId}")
    public ChallengeSummary createChallengeSummary(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        return reportsService.createChallengeSummary(userId);
    }
}

I've ensured the following:

All controllers are annotated with @RestController.
The package structure is correct, and the main application class is in the root package.
The application starts without any errors.
Accessing Swagger UI via http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html.

Despite these steps, Swagger UI still shows "No operations defined in spec!". Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Remove this line of code from springdoc.packages-to-scan="blossom.reports_service" application.properties
And another change for Setup-controller, change annotation @Controller to @RestController because OpenAPI won't recognize @Controller annotation

Thanks, that was definitely in the right direction.
I had to change the package of 'springdoc.packagesToScan' and update 'springdoc.pathsToMatch' value, to include everything
